# The best pratice to parse PDF forms fields with PHP5

Tags: php, forms, pdf, parsing

I have PDFs with filled out form fields from a customer, which have to be parsed with PHP5 and written into  a MySQL-DB.

With Google I only find libraries, like Zend_Pdf, which are helpful for creating or manipulating PDFs but not for parsing for form fields. Do you know any libraries or classes for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/). It allows you to manipulate PDF files in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I figured out, that pdftk has the option "generate_fdf" which delievers a FDF, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376502/get-fields-in-a-pdf-file-using-php

But somehow I only see the fields inside the FDF

Comment: It seems now, that the delivered PDFs are not well-formed. When I try another FDF I get usable results

Comment: This answer is not even PHP related.

Comment: This Pdftk is not able to extract XFA data from form pdf.

Comment: Please suggest any solution to extract xfa from form pdf using pdftk.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project on github... [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk)  I was looking for the same thing and found this project which appears to provide a nice wrapper to pdftk for use in PHP.

Comment: This Pdftk is not able to extract XFA data from form pdf.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
The originaly posted solution only returns all form fields, without their filled values. To retrieve field values the approach of @max-matti in the comments can be used.

---

This solution works without any additional dependencies/requirements:

Use the `FPDM` class: https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm.

Then define your own class that extends `FPDM`  and retrieves the protected `value_entries` after calling `merge()` on your PDF file.

Your class:

```
use \FPDM;

class FPDMHelper extends FPDM {
    public function getFormFields() {
        $this->merge();
        return $this->value_entries;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$pathToYourFile = __DIR__.'\your-file.pdf';

$pdf = new FPDMHelper($pathToYourFile);

$formFields = $pdf->getFormFields();
print_r($formFields);
```

Comment: This only returns all empty fields and not a single non-empty form field. I tried by filling the form with FPDM, saving it and then reading it back in with your method.

Comment: True! I have misread the question and posted an insufficient answer. It should be possible to read out filled values with FPDM though!

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this using FPDM however I was able to hack together this:
https://gist.github.com/MaxMatti/07e5d0ce13659ed083bb064d01e548f6