# PHP regex code to extract FDF data

Tags: php, regex, fdf

I am trying to parse a FDF file using PHP, and regex. But I just cant get my head around regex. I am stuck parsing the file to generate a array.

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj 
<<
/FDF 
<<
/Fields [
<<
/V (email@email.com)
/T (field_email)
>> 
<<
/V (John)
/T (field_name)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (field_reference)
>>]
>>
>>
endobj 
trailer

<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

Current function (source:http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fdf.php)

```
function parse2($file) {
 if (!preg_match_all("/<<\s*\/V([^>]*)>>/x", $file,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER))
         return;
 for ($i=0;$i<count($out);$i++) {
         $pattern = "<<.*/V\s*(.*)\s*/T\s*(.*)\s*>>";
         $thing = $out[$i][1];
         if (eregi($pattern,$out[$i][0],$regs)) {
                 $key = $regs[2];
                 $val = $regs[1];
                 $key = preg_replace("/^\s*\(/","",$key);
                 $key = preg_replace("/\)$/","",$key);
                 $key = preg_replace("/\\\/","",$key);
                 $val = preg_replace("/^\s*\(/","",$val);
                 $val = preg_replace("/\)$/","",$val);
                 $matches[$key] = $val;
         }
 }
 return $matches;
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [field_email)
    ] => email@email.com)

    [field_name)
    ] => John)

    [field_reference)
    ] => )

)
```

Why does it conclude the `)` and new line? I know this problem is trivial for someone that understands regex expressions. So help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

Your initial expression simply finds the entire block of text which represents each key and value set. Then in your clean up section, you're looking for a close paran which is followed immediately by a end of string `\)$` but I'm sure there are additional characters between the close paran and the end of the string.

Instead I'd handle all this in one operation. This expression will:

- find the field value

  - trim the surrounding parens off
  - and place into capture group 1
- find the name of the value  and place into capture group 2

  - trim the `field_` substring off
  - trim the surrounding parens off
  - and place into capture group 2
- requires the options: case insensitive, and multi-line

`^\/V\s\(([^)]*)\)[\r\n]*^\/T\s\(field_([^)]*)\)`

[image]

## Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/i7oL3f3fSt)

**Sample Text**

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj 
<<
/FDF 
<<
/Fields [
<<
/V (email@email.com)
/T (field_email)
>> 
<<
/V (John)
/T (field_name)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (field_reference)
>>]
>>
>>
endobj 
trailer

<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = /V (email@email.com)
/T (field_email)
[0][1] = email@email.com
[0][2] = email

[1][0] = /V (John)
/T (field_name)
[1][1] = John
[1][2] = name

[2][0] = /V ()
/T (field_reference)
[2][1] = 
[2][2] = reference
```

---

## Or

If you wanted retain the `field_` substring, then you can simply remove that from the expression like so:

`^\/V\s\(([^)]*)\)[\r\n]*^\/T\s\(([^)]*)\)`

[image]

Comment: adding the \ims flags, and the regex works perfectly in php (preg_match_all("/^\/V\s\(([^)]*)\)[\r\n]*^\/T\s\(field_([^)]*)\)/ims", $file,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER); Also in the mean time found http://www.debuggex.com/ great for debugging

Comment: Regexp are not great for parsing FDF, e.g. Chrome submits FDF `[<</T(field)/V(value)>>]`