# How to implement an editable textarea component on a PDF generated by TCPDF library?

Tags: php, pdf, textarea, tcpdf, scrollable

I am trying to create an editable HTML `textarea` component using TCPDF API library. I want to display a scrollable text box on the screen.

Can this be done?

Current TCPDF examples include these:  https://tcpdf.org/examples/
I know PDFs can have editable components, but I am not sure how to create them with TCPDF, if it is at all possible.

**TD;DR:**  how can I generate a page with a scrollable textarea using PHP + TCPDF?

**Linked Answer using another library (mPDF):**

Note that while [How to create editable Pdf form in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610629/how-to-create-editable-pdf-form-in-php) may work, it does not make use of TCPDF library.  My existing codebase relies heavily on TCPDF, I would like to explore the possibility of using TCPDF before I consider adding another library ...

i.e. I rather have an answer of "Not possible" than to use another library at this time.

Comment: You'll need to do some more homework before this is on-topic, right now it's way too abstract and there's a multitude of ways this could work out, each of which is a lot to explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create editable Pdf form in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610629/how-to-create-editable-pdf-form-in-php)

Comment: @tadman, what kind of homework do I need to do?  I need an editable HTML textarea component using TCPDF.   How can I make this into a more concrete question?

Comment: You'll need to have some code, any code, that demonstrate what you're trying to do. If you're note even sure where to start, that's fine, but it's off-topic here. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is two-fold.

First, you can use a typical form example, like here:  https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_054/ 
However, you cannot see editable fields in a browser, at least you cannot in Mozilla Firefox 56.0.2 as the time of this writing.  (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1006115)

What you need to do is open the generated PDF in a different viewer that supports editable form fields, such as Adobe PDF reader/other.

Then you can fill out the textarea and if text size exceeds the area of the form element, it will have scroll bars added to the textarea.