# Read & list fillable fields on PDF's to create catalog

Tags: apache, pdf, lamp

Problem:

I'm managing nearly 3,000 PDF's on my servers. 
They are divided up by state in sub-directories. 
In many cases, these are PDF forms created by the states themselves and I added my own fillable and editable fields to the PDF's and the fields all have unique identifying field names. Some pdfs have hundreds of fields. up to now I haven't cataloged which fields were added to which forms

My Need:

I could really use a tool/utility that I can run on the server. read and return a list of all the fillable fields that are on each PDF (by state/filename) so I can create a catalog.

Someone had told me there is a way to do this with JAVA or Itext etc but that's Greek to me and I just know my way around PHP and admittedly don't have any depth at all with other languages.

Comment: No Response so I will say my answer is; there is no answer at this time

Comment: A couple of other folks have been looking for more or less the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823266/php-extract-fdf-fields-as-an-array-from-a-pdf Scroll down to the response to Murray (new parsing function). It's not a full solution but may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up and I will look into that further - any potential lead to a solution is greatly appreciated!